# Delete elements from array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Maybe by title seems a easy question, but I didn´t know how to do the shortest title for my question.
I want to delete elements from array on javascript, yes, but what I am looking for exactly is delete from array mismatched elements with other array on javascript (maybe it could be title, but too large).
**For example:**

```
Array A=> [a, b, c, d]  
Array B=> [b,d]  
Array C = deleteMismatchedElements(A,B)  
Array C (after function)-> [b,d]
```

I suppose that using a nested foreach loop it could be possible, but I wonder if there is a better way, something as a "native" implemented method that could be called, or similar...

Thank you very much.

Comment: Based on your example, `C = B` would do the job.

Comment: for the first glance i thought you need arrays difference, but i cannot understand what you really want ?

Comment: You should probably provide an example where B is not a subset of A. I believe you are looking for array intersection. That would be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1885557/218196

Comment: You want the __set intersection__ of the arrays. Just so you know the terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var C = [];
for(var i = 0; i < B.length; i ++){
    if(A.indexOf(B[i]) > -1){
        C.push(B[i]);
    }
}
```

What this does is

1. Creates array `C`
2. Runs through each item in `B`
3. `if` `B[i]` is in `A`, add it to `C`

Comment: `A.filter(b.includes.bind(b))`

Comment: ... Wait wait wait let me get my head around this. JavaScript has a filter method for arrays. What have I been doing with my life for the past month?

Comment: There you go: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1885569/218196

Comment: @FelixKling I think mine is simpler :D

Comment: @Benjamin: true, but `includes` doesn't seem to be native :P

Comment: It is, it's just new :) (It'll take a while though because everyone is busy with ES6 now :D)

Comment: @Benjamin: Oh, ES7. That doesn't count :P