# removes elements from array javascript (contrary intersection)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Yesterday nigth I maked this question [Delete elements from array javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711165/delete-elements-from-array-javascript)
But I mistook, my explanation and my example were about an intersection between two arrays.
What I wanted to ask is about how remove elements on array that doesn´t exist on other array.
**Example**:

```
Array A=> [a, b, c, d]  
Array B=> [b, d, e]  
Array C= removeElementsNotIn(A, B);  
Array C (after function)-> [a,c]
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` to selectively remove items that don't pass a test.

```
var c = a.filter(function(item) { 
    return b.indexOf(item) < 0; // Returns true for items not found in b.
});
```

In a function:

```
function removeElementsNotIn(a, b) {
    return a.filter(function(item) { 
       return b.indexOf(item) < 0; // Returns true for items not found in b.
    });
}
var arrayC = removeElementsNotIn(arrayA, arrayB);
```

If you want to get **really** fancy (advanced only), you can create a function that returns the filtering function, like so:

```
function notIn(array) {
    return function(item) {
        return array.indexOf(item) < 0;
    };
}
// notIn(arrayB) returns the filter function.
var c = arrayA.filter(notIn(arrayB));
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Second Rikhdo
full code:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = [4,5,6,7,8,9];

var new_array = a.filter(function(item) { 
  return b.indexOf(item) < 0; // Returns true for items not found in b.
});
alert(new_array);
// results: array[1,2,3]
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cmoa7Lw7/

Answer (score 1):

```js
a1 = ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5'];
a2 = ['s4', 's5', 's6'];
a3 = [];

function theFunction(ar1, ar2) {
  var ar3 = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
    if (ar2.indexOf(ar1[i]) != -1) {
      ar3.push(ar1[i]);
    }
  }
  return ar3;
}

a3 = theFunction(a1, a2);

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = a3.toString();
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### 2022 answer

There is one more alternative which is easier to read:

```js
const c = a.filter(item => !b.includes(item))
```