# How to remove objects from an array having values that are present in an other simple array (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following two arrays:

```
SimpleArray = [2,3];  
ObjectArray = [{
    id: 1, 
    name: 'charles'
},{
    id: 2, 
    name: 'john'
},{
    id: 3, 
    name: 'allen'
},{
    id: 4, 
    name: 'jack'
}];
```

I want to remove objects present in `ObjectArray` that have id's equal to the values present in `SimpleArray`.

Comment: Loop through `ObjectArray` and remove items where the `id` is in `SimpleArray`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [removes elements from array javascript (contrary intersection)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715271/removes-elements-from-array-javascript-contrary-intersection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete data from original array then use **[`Array#splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** method

```js
SimpleArray = [2, 3];
ObjectArray = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'charles'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'john'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'alen'
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: 'jack'
}];

for (var i = 0; i < ObjectArray.length; i++) {
  if (SimpleArray.indexOf(ObjectArray[i].id) > -1) {
    ObjectArray.splice(i, 1);
    i--;
  }
}

console.log(ObjectArray);
```

---

In case you need to generate new filtered array then use **[`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method

```js
SimpleArray = [2, 3];
ObjectArray = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'charles'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'john'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'alen'
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: 'jack'
}];

var res = ObjectArray.filter(function(v) {
  return SimpleArray.indexOf(v.id) > -1
})

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you. @Pranav C Balan

Comment: @Taahaa : glad to help you :)